# Использование в меню переданного значения из другой активности

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity, bottom-navigation-view

Имеется следующий вопрос: создается главная активность, на которой присутствует только `BottomNavigationView`. При нажатии на элемент меню, на активность добавляется фрагмент со списком названий статей. При нажатии на название статьи открывается новая активность, в которой полностью представлена статья. Однако когда на `ActionBar` (да, знаю, что стоит использовать `ToolBar`) нажимаю кнопку `вверх`, открывается главная активность. А возможно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы по нажатию кнопки `вверх` открывалась активность с фрагментом, который был на активности до того как мы перешли на новую активность? Думал сначала через `Bundle` сделать, но не совсем понимаю, как через полученное значение обратиться потом к элементу меню, либо же вообще никак?

Comment: в onSaveInstanceState() главной активности сохраняйте метку о текущем открытом фрагменте, в onRestoreInstanceState() по этой метке открывайте нужный фрагмент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то не нужно использовать Bundle, нужно переопределить метод нажатия на кнопку вверх:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish() // обычное закрытие активности как на кнопку назад 
            return(true);
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Или можно попробовать переопределить метод OnSupportNavigateUp(), в теле этого метода тоже вызывать finish()